# How to declare hundreds of features in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I have a very big table in the following stucture:

```
user, product, action

user1, productA, actionA

user1, productA, actionB

user1, productA, actionB

user2, productF, actionA

user3, productZ, actionC
```

I would like to transpose it to the following:

Stage1: retrieve specific products X actions

```
user, productA_actionA, productB_actionA, …, productA_actionB, productB_actionB…

user1, 1, 0, ..., 0,0, ...

user1, 0, 0, ..., 1,0, ...

user1, 0, 0, ..., 1,0, ...

user2, 0, 0, ..., 0,0, ...
```

I have the array that contains the specific combinations:

```
[(productA,actionA) ,(productB,actionA) ,… ,(productA,actionB) ,(productB,actionB) …]
```

Stage2:  group my users, and summing their products and actions

```
user, productA_actionA, productB_actionA, …, productA_actionB, productB_actionB…

user1, 1, 0, ..., **2**,0, ...

user2, 0, 0, ..., 0,0, ...
```

I tried using the `withColumn` `function` for each feature but this takes forever:

```
for ( (productID,productAction) <- productsCombination ) {
    newTable = newTable.withColumn("Product_"+productID+"_"+productAction, when(col("product_action_id") === productAction and col("product_id") === productID, $"product_count").otherwise(0))
```

Here's an example shows what I want to do :

[image: Example]

Any advice?

Comment: your question is really unclear,  I've read it  three times and still not understand the structure of your data and what you really want to do ?

Comment: The structure of my data is an event table, all events my users do: view  productA, add product B to cart, remove from cart...
I want to make specific products X actions as a feature
Then aggregating all features, grouping by the userID

Comment: @HarounMohammedi, may be this will be more clear: https://prnt.sc/fab9gl

Comment: Yeah effectively, this is more clearer I just added the image to the question. my question is : is your answer does the work ?

Comment: Pivot + use select instead of many withColumns

Comment: thanks @HarounMohammedi.     Yes, my solution works, but it's not efficient at all! I need to scan the whole table for every feature, in case I have 2,000 features = scanning 2,000 times...    I would like to scan once and build all features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to understand the question properly but I considered your screenshot and this is based on the output of your screenshot.
As  T. Gawęda said, you should use Pivot. Note that `pivot` is only available with Spark 1.6+

Considering this is your source DataFrame

```
scala> df.show()
+-----+-------+---------------+
| User|Product|         Action|
+-----+-------+---------------+
|user1|      A|         Viewed|
|user1|      A|         Viewed|
|user1|      A|         Viewed|
|user1|      C|      AddToCart|
|user1|      A|RemovedFromCart|
|user2|      B|         Viewed|
|user2|      B|         Viewed|
|user3|      A|         Viewed|
|user3|      A|      AddToCart|
|user4|      B|      AddToCart|
|user5|      A|         Viewed|
+-----+-------+---------------+
```

Now since you need to Pivot on two columns, you can concat them into one using the `concat_ws` function provided by Apache Spark and then Pivot the concatenated column, perform a `groupBy` on `Users` and use `count` on `Products` as the aggregate function.

```
df.withColumn("combined", concat_ws("_", $"Product", $"Action"))
  .groupBy("User")
  .pivot("combined")
  .agg(count($"Product")).show()

+-----+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| User|A_AddToCart|A_RemovedFromCart|A_Viewed|B_AddToCart|B_Viewed|C_AddToCart|
+-----+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+
|user1|          0|                1|       3|          0|       0|          1|
|user2|          0|                0|       0|          0|       2|          0|
|user3|          1|                0|       1|          0|       0|          0|
|user4|          0|                0|       0|          1|       0|          0|
|user5|          0|                0|       1|          0|       0|          0|
+-----+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, yet:  a. It seems to have poor performance like my solution (for over withColumn).   b. I would like to create features (new columns) only for the combination of Product_Action that's in myList = [(productA_actionA),(productC_actionA),(productC_ActionB)...]

Comment: Seems like that could be easily accomplished with a `filter` just before this pivoting.

Comment: Thanks @JoeK, but still, this takes to compute forever, I have millions of users and hundreds of features, isn't there a faster way? maybe lowering and manipulating in RDD or sparse vector?